# fetching timeseries/range data in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and trying to see if it fits my data query needs. I am populating test data in a table and fetching them using cql client in Golang.

I am storing time series data in Cassandra, sorted by timestamp. I store data on a per-minute basis.

Schema is like this:
parent:    string
child:     string
bytes:     int
val2:      int
timestamp: date/time

I need to answer queries where a timestamp range is provided and a childname is given. The result needs to be the bytes value in that time range(Single value, not series) I made a primary key(child, timestamp). I followed this approach rather than the column-family, comparator-type with timeuuid since that was not supported in cql.

Since the data stored in every timestamp(every minute) is the accumulated value, when I get a range query for time t1 to t2, I need to find the bytes value at t2, bytes value at t1 and subtract the 2 values before returning. This works fine if t1 and t2 actually had entries in the table. If they do not, I need to find those times between (t1, t2) that have data and return the difference.

One approach I can think of is to "select * from tablename WHERE timestamp <= t2 AND timestamp >= t1;" and then find the difference between the first and last entry in this array of rows returned. Is this the best way to do it? Since MIN and MAX queries are not supported, is there is a way to find the maximum timestamp in the table less than a given value? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your approach is correct you have to use > and < range only. I have doubt that you can use >= and <=, but you can use > and < and i guess that is the only way as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will go ahead with that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you storing each entry as a new row with a different partition key(first column in the Primary key)? If so, select * from x where f < a and f > b is a cluster wide query, which will cause you problems. Consider adding a "fake" partition key, or use a partition key per date / week / month etc. so that your queries hit a single partition.

Also, your queries in cassandra are >= and <= even if you specify > and <. If you need strictly greater than or less than, you'll need to filter client side.